# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces in a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> Consider the following:
>
> $$ Q = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} ,\qquad X= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^3 $$

I have these questions:

> 1. Is $\lambda = 1$ an autovalue of $Q$? Why?

Yes, because:

$$\lambda \text{ is an autovalue of } A \iff |A - \lambda I_n | = 0$$

and in this case you have:

$$|A - \lambda I_n | = |Q - I_3 | = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 0$$

> 2. Find all the autovalues of $Q$, and their geometric/algebraic multiplicities.

$$A \text{ is symmetric} \implies A \text{ is diagonalizable}$$

$$A \text{ is diagonalizable} \implies p_A(\lambda) \text{ is totally decomposable}$$

$$p_A(\lambda) \text{ is totally decomposable} \implies \begin{matrix}det(A) = \lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2 \cdot \cdots \cdot \lambda_n \\ tr(A) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n\end{matrix}$$

Because I know $\lambda_1 = 1$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda_2 \cdot \lambda_3 = 4 \\
\lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 5
\end{cases}
\implies
\lambda_{2,3}^2 - 5 \lambda_{2,3} + 4 = 0
\implies
\lambda_2 = 1 ,\quad \lambda_3 = 4
$$

So the autovalues and the geometric/algebraic multiplicities are:

$$
\lambda_1 = 1 ,\quad \mu(1) = 2 \\
\lambda_2 = 4 ,\quad \mu(4) = 1 ,\quad m(4) = 1
$$

To find $m(1)$ I can use the following:

$$A \in\mathscr M_\mathbb R(n) \text{ is diagonalizable} \iff m(\lambda_1) + m(\lambda_2) + \cdots + m(\lambda_n) = n$$

So:

$$m(1) = n - m(4) = 3 - 1 = 2$$

> 3. Find an orthogonal basis for every eigenspaces.

I suppose I have to use the *Spectral Theorem*, but I really don't know how to do.

*UPDATE: I've tried to solve this question using the method suggested by [Michael Seifert](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1915484/306889).*

For the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 1$ I have:

$$
V_1 = Q - I_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
dim(V_1) = 3 - rk(Q - I_3) = 3 - 1 = 2
$$

So the cartesian equation of $V_1$ is:

$$
x + y + z = 0
$$

I search for the parametric equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = \alpha \\
y = \beta \\
z = - \alpha - \beta
\end{cases}
$$

So a basis for $V_1$ is the following:

$$
\mathscr B_{V_1} = \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Now I can  apply the *Gram-Schmidt* process to find the solution. The same for $\lambda_2 = 4$.

> 4. Does exists a solution of $X^T Q X = 0$ with $X \neq 0$? Why?

Also for this, I don't know how to find the answer.

---

My questions are the following:

1. Are *(1)* and *(2)* right?
2. Is there a faster way to solve *(1)* and *(2)*?
3. How can I solve *(3)* and *(4)*?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of the *determinant* of a matrix?  There's a faster way to solve (1) and (2) using them, but some contemporary texts try to avoid determinants as much as possible.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sorry if this is off topic but why do they avoid determinants ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus:  the way they're presented in many linear algebra courses, they're basically black magic;  and there are other ways to do calculations that might provide more intuition.  See Sheldon Axler's 1995 paper ["Down with Determinants!"](http://www.axler.net/DwD.html)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That is very interesting. I have just finished my own development of the subject (which should appear soon on youtube), I present determinants as very natural, being the unique function invariant under row operations.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I've solved **(1)** using the determinant and is pretty fast (two equal columns $\implies det = 0$). I know I can solve part of **(2)** with a determinant, but I thought it was more difficult (because you obtain a third degree equation). Edit: I've see now your answer.

Comment: For part 4, do you know anything about quadratic forms and positive-definiteness?

Comment: @amd Yes, I know a bit.

Comment: For part 3, you can avoid the Gram-Schmidt process since you have a symmetric matrix and are working in $\mathbb R^3$. The eigenspaces are mutually orthogonal, so the cross product of the two basis vectors you found for $V_1$ will be in $V_4$. Take the cross product of that with one of the $V_1$ vectors and you’ll have a vector in $V_1$ that’s orthogonal to the latter. Now normalize them all.

Comment: Back to part 4: $X^TQX$ is a quadratic form. What do the eigenvalues of $Q$ that you’ve computed tell you about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily faster, but another way to solve (2) involves using the determinant more directly.  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, we have
$$
|Q - \lambda I_3| = \begin{vmatrix} 2 - \lambda & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2- \lambda & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2- \lambda \end{vmatrix}
$$ 
$$ 0 = (2 - \lambda)\left( (2 - \lambda)^2 - 1) \right) - (2 - \lambda - 1) + (1 - (2 - \lambda))  
$$
$$ 
0 = 4 - 9 \lambda + 6 \lambda^2 - \lambda^3
$$
You've already been clued in that $\lambda = 1$ is a root of this polynomial, so you can factor out $(1 - \lambda)$ to get
$$
0 = (1 - \lambda)(4 - 5 \lambda + \lambda^2)
$$
and the roots of the remaining factor are $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 4$.  In fact, this becomes
$$
0 = (1 - \lambda)^2 (4 - \lambda);
$$
since 1 is a double root of the polynomial, it is an eigenvalue of $Q$ with multiplicity 2, while 4 is an eigenvalue with multiplicity 1.

As far as (3) goes, here's what I would do:  if $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvector $\lambda = 1$, then it must be the case that
$$
(Q - I_3) \mathbf{v} = 0,
$$
i.e., $\mathbf{v}$ must lie in the null space of
$$
Q - I_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
You can then use the usual sorts of techniques to find the null vectors of this matrix, and use the Gram-Schmidt process (if necessary) to make the basis orthogonal.  Similarly, finding the null space of $Q - 4 I_3$ will yield the eigenvector for $\lambda = 4$ (note that there will only be one up to scaling, since this eigenspace is one-dimensional.

Finally, for (4):  suppose that $X$ existed such that $X^T Q X = 0$.    One of the neat facts about eigenvectors of symmetric matrices is that they span the entire vector space and can be chosen to be orthogonal;  so you must have $X = \alpha_1 X_{1} + \alpha_2 X_2 + \alpha_3 X_3$, where the $X_i$ vectors are all mutually orthogonal, and where the only way to get $X = 0$ is to have $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = 0$.  Try plugging this in to the quantity $X^T Q X$ and see what it tells you.

Comment: **[2]** At the beginning I'd try to solve *(2)* like you, but once arrived to $0=4−9\lambda+6\lambda^2−\lambda^3$ I did not know how to continue (I'm very bad with decomposition). Anyway I like the way you *factor out* $(1-\lambda)$, I did not really think about it. **[3]** I've tried to solve *(3)* but I'm not sure if it's correct (I've added it to my question). **[4]** Sorry but I not understand.

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ:  Your solution to (3) is correct, once you apply Gram-Schmidt.  As far as (4) goes, I'd rather not give the entire solution away, but I've added an additional hint;  hopefully it helps.

Comment: $X^T Q X = \Delta \neq 0$, where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix. Is this possible?

Comment: In this problem $X$ is a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: @amd:  If that's the case, then my answer would have to change (though the method I've outlined about should still work.)  Hopefully ᴜsᴇʀ can confirm this reading.

Comment: At the very top of the question, we have $X\in\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Ah, so we do;  I thought it must be a matrix.  I'll edit my hint accordingly.

Comment: I'm already trying to find a solution, with yours and @amd suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For part 3 you want to find all vectors $(x,y,z)$ such that

$$x+y+z=0$$ that is your matrix for eigenvalue $1$
it is easy to see that the two independent solutions are $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ you then need to orthogonalize them. For the eigenvalue $4$, the matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}
-2&1&1\\1&-2&1\\1&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$ this has rank $2$ and it gives the eigenvector $(1,1,1)$.

For the fourth part $Q$ is diagonalised by an orthogonal transfrom so it sufficed to solve this for a diagonal matrix, and it boils down to finding $x,y,z$ such that $4x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ which has only $x=y=z=0$ if you are working over the reals.